# splitting an array and find maximal |max (L) -max (R)|

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I have a general question in programming.
Suppose I have an array, I need to find the index K that divides the array into two parts L, R so that the value
|max (L) -max (R)| Is maximal.

- max(L) is the highest number in the L part
- K points to the first member in R

Comment: try interpolation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a problem that reduces to only 2 viable candidates for a solution: either *K* splits off the first value from the rest, or the last value from the rest, giving you a small part of just one value, and a large part with the remaining values, including the maximum value.

Suppose the maximum value in the array can be found at index *M*, then one of the two parts will have that value and it will be *Max(Part)*. The other part should have a maximum value that is as small as possible. Consequently that part should be reduced to just one value: adding one more value to that part could never decrease its maximum value.

If the overall maximum value is at one of the ends of the array, then there is no choice, and the *small* part will be chopped off the array at the other end of it.

When the overall maximum value is not at an end of the array, there are two possibilities: choose the one where the chopped off value will be the lowest. In other words, *K* will be either 1 or n-1 (in zero-based indexing), and this can be determined in constant time, i.e. *O(1)*.

Answer (score 2):

Actually to solve this question we can do it in constant time.

1.Since the list must be divided in two either list A or list B will contain the leftmost or rightmost element.

2. Adding values to our list can only *increase* the maximum element of a list, so it is never desirable to have a list of size larger than 1

So all we need to do is look at the head and tail, take the smallest A, and make the rest of the list B

For example consider 6,7,7,3,2,6,4

A = [4], (smallest head/tail), B = [6,7,7,3,2,6]

Comment: I think I was first to post this solution, but well done in finding it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it in O(n) with some preparation:

- Make two arrays, `maxL[]` and `maxR[]` equal in size to the original array
- Walk the original array starting from the left, setting `maxL[i]` to the max value so far
- Walk the original array again starting from the right, setting `maxR[i]` to the max value so far
- Now walk both `maxL[]` and `maxR[]` in any direction, looking for `k` such that the value of `ABS(maxL[k] - maxR[k])` is maximized; return `k`.

Comment: it looks like the answer is always k=2 or k=n-2, am I right?

Comment: Note that in a realistic implementation of this approach, you wouldn't actually explicitly build both arrays, since you can compute the other one's values on-the-fly in the same pass that's checking `ABS(maxL[k] - maxR[k])`.

Comment: @user8446864 Right. This does not seem to be a very interesting programming problem after all, simply a programming-related puzzle. Finding a split where the absolute difference is minimal sounds like a more interesting problem.

Comment: @ruakh Right, that's a valid optimization. It turns out to be unnecessary, too, because the problem has an O(1) solution. Finding `min` of the same function would probably be more interesting.